# insert echo into the specific html element like div which has an id or class

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{background:#666666;}
div{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("juliver", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hi");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo '<img src="'.$row['name'].'" />';  
echo "<div>".$row['name']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$row['title']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$row['description']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$row['link']."</div>";
echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close($con);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

the above code works.

now, I want to insert this

```
echo '<img src="'.$row['name'].'" />'; 
echo "<div>".$row['name']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$row['title']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$row['description']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$row['link']."</div>";
echo "<br />";
```

into the specified div or other element in the html, example, i will insert this

```
echo '<img src="'.$row['name'].'" />';
```

into the html element .

I dont know how to do this, please help me. Thanks

Juliver

Comment: You want to insert *what* and *where*? Please revise your question

Comment: you need to ensure those keys exist in the $row array with isset($row['something']) before using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer to the basic.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only things I can think of are

1. including files
2. replacing elements within files using preg_match_all
3. using assigned variables

I have recently been using str_replace and setting text in the HTML portion like so

```
{{TEXT_TO_REPLACE}}
```

using file_get_contents() you can grab html data and then organise it how you like.

here is a demo

```
myReplacementCodeFunction(){
  $text = '<img src="'.$row['name'].'" />'; 
  $text .= "<div>".$row['name']."</div>";
  $text .= "<div>".$row['title']."</div>";
  $text .= "<div>".$row['description']."</div>";
  $text .= "<div>".$row['link']."</div>";
  $text .= "<br />";
  return $text;
}

$htmlContents = file_get_contents("myhtmlfile.html");
$htmlContents = str_replace("{{TEXT_TO_REPLACE}}", myReplacementCodeFunction(), $htmlContents);
echo $htmlContents;
```

and now a demo html file:

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      body{background:#666666;}
      div{border:1px solid red;}
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{TEXT_TO_REPLACE}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have been using phtml (5 years later) which makes this easier now. You can use this in the middle of the html: <?= phpcodehere ?> and to make a foreach you can do this: <?php foreach(x as y): ?> loop stuff, then <?php endforeach; ?>

Answer (score 3):

if yo want to place in an div like 

i have same work and i do it like

```
<div id="content>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<img src="'.$row['name'].'" />';  
echo "<div>".$row['name']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$row['title']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$row['description']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$row['link']."</div>";
echo "<br />";
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write the php code in another file and include it in the proper place where you want it.

AJAX is also used to display HTML content that is formed by PHP into a specified HTML tag.

Using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({url: "test.php"}).done(function( html ) {
    $("#results").append(html);
});
```

Above code will execute *test.php* and result will be displayed in the element with id *results*.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that you can do it in PHP when HTML is already generated. What you can do is to use JavaScript or jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('//ID//').innerHTML="HTML CODE";
```

If you have to do it when your URI changes you can get the URI and then split it and then insert the HTML in script dynamically:

```
var url = document.URL;
// to get url and then use split() to check the parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to specifically target an element with php, you can either embed the php code between a div tag or use jquery which would be longer.

Comment: ahmm.. I guess the best way is trough jquery or javascript or ajax as well, can you give a thing on how to do it on jquery please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
    $string = '';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    //this will combine all the results into one string
    $string .= '<img src="'.$row['name'].'" />
                <div>'.$row['name'].'</div>
                <div>'.$row['title'].'</div>
                <div>'.$row['description'].'</div>
                <div>'.$row['link'].'</div><br />';

    //or this will add the individual result in an array
 /*
     $yourHtml[] = $row;
*/
    }
```

then you echo the $tring to the place you want it to be

```
<div id="place_here">
   <?php echo $string; ?>
   <?php 
     //or
    /*
      echo '<img src="'.$yourHtml[0]['name'].'" />;//change the index, or you just foreach loop it
    */
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that: the entire string is concatenated. I wasn't sure if you want to print it individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat it by fetching again the data

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 //another html element
 <div>$row['name']</div>
 <div>$row['title']</div>
 //and so on
 }
```

or you need to put it on the variable and call display it again on other html element

```
 $name = $row['name'];
 $title = $row['title']
 //and so on
```

then put it on the other element, but if you want to call all the data of each id, you need to do the first code

Answer (score 0):

Well from your code its clear that $row['name'] is the location of the image on the file, try including the div tag like this

```
echo '<div>' .$row['name']. '</div>' ;
```

and do the same for others, let me know if it works because you said that one snippet of your code is giving the desired result so try this and if the div has some class specifier then do this

```
echo '<div class="whatever_it_is">' . $row['name'] . '</div'> ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put  div with single quotation around it.  `' '` the `Div` must be in the middle of single quotation . i'm gonna clear it with one example :

```
<?php
        echo '<div id="output">'."Identify".'<br>'.'<br>';
        echo 'Welcome '."$name";
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'Web Mail: '."$email";
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'Department of '."$dep";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "$maj";
        '</div>'
?>
```

hope be useful.

Answer (score -2):

I use this or similar code to inject PHP messages into a fixed DIV positioned in front of other elements (z-index: 9999) just for convenience at the development stage.

Each PHP message passes into my 'custom_message()' function and is further conveyed into the innard of preformatted DIV created by echoed JS.

There can be as many as it gets, all put inside that fixed DIV, one under the other.

```
<style>
    #php_messages {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    .php_message {
        background-color: #333;
        border: red solid 1px;
        color: white;
        font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
        margin: 1em;
        padding: 1em;
    }
</style>

<div id="php_messages"></div>

<?php
    function custom_message($output) {
        echo
            '
                <script>
                    var
                        el = document.createElement("DIV");
                    el.classList.add("php_message");
                    el.innerHTML = \''.$output.'\';
                    document.getElementById("php_messages").appendChild(el);
                </script>
            ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.